# Tokenize whitespace character(s) in C

Tags: c, tokenize, strtok

I'm trying to tokenize a string with multiple spaces. For example, `"yes___no"`, where the underscores are spaces. Using `strtok(string, " ");`

But I am getting a seg fault and after debugging I see after I tokenize the second string is `"\024\002"` and when printing this incorrect string I get my error.

Comment: Maybe you can add more code? There should be something like: for (t = strtok(string, " "); t; t = strtok(NULL, " ")){ /*do something with t */ }

Comment: Look at this example: http://ideone.com/phSOJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change a string literal.

```
/* does not work */
char *data = "yes no";
strtok(data, " ");
```

The `strtok` above will try to break the `data` at the space by writing a `'\0'` there: `data[3] = '\0';`, but string literals are not modifiable. Try instead

```
/* works */
char data[] = "yes no";
strtok(data, " ");
```

---

Edit: copy a string literal to a character array

```
char *data = "string literal";
/* ... */
char *copy;
size_t datalen = strlen(data) + 1;
copy = malloc(datalen);
if (copy != NULL) {
    strcpy(copy, data);
    /* use copy now ... strtok(copy, " "); ... or whatever you need */
    free(copy);
} else {
    /* no memory. Tell user to upgrade computer :-) */
}
```

Comment: Then how would I go about splitting a (char *) since this is how I am getting the string to token.

Comment: Well ... just copy the string literal to an array of characters (or allocated memory). See edit